# How to know (or specify) the localhost port used by R shiny (when running in local)

Tags: r, localhost, port, shiny

I would like to know what port R shiny will use to display the app. I can see on some forums that the port should be 8100, but when I run the app, the chosen posrt changes every time R is restarted.

Is there any way to specify this port? Or at least to know the port that will be used, to use it in another part of the script?

Answer (score 10):

There is a `port=` parameter you can specify to `runApp`. The default value is `NULL` which chooses a random port. Read the `?runApp` help page for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Rapid, clear, straightforward... a perfect answer! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to (or can't) specify the port (maybe running shiny from inside Rmarkdown), get the port this way:

> session$clientData$url_port

Answer (score 5):

From the runApp documentation:

> If the port is not specified, and the shiny.port option is set (with options(shiny.port = XX)), then that port will be used. Otherwise, use a random port.

So simply do this:

```
# will set the default shiny port to 8100
options(shiny.port = 8100)
```

and subsequent calls to `runApp` will launch the app on port `8100`